# link_to show action with associated id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model:

```
class RoomType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rooms
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room_type
end
```

In `rooms/show.html.erb` I would like to link to the room type:

`<%= link_to(room_types_path(:code => @room.type_code)`

> http://test.com/room_types?code=MMC

The desired output is:

> http://test.com/types/:id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `path` should be:

```
types_path(@room.type)
```

So your link will become:

```
<%= link_to "Room Types", types_path(@room.type) %>
```